# Django server fail silently, doesn't give response to any request

Tags: python, linux, django, debian, localhost

I have a project, based on Django. We add new bunch of apps (3-4), and server don't response on any request. **Log is clear**. It even don't log GET/POST requests. In browser I see:

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
```

I guess, that problem in new apps, so I removed it from `INSTALLED_APPS`, but result is the same. So I tried to find problem in `settings.py`, but result is still same.

After that, I checked my ports by `netstat` and `nmap`, and I was stunned, because port 8000 is empty.

```
root@artem-debian:/home/artem# nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-19 10:20 EEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00018s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
3306/tcp open  mysql
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.15
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.76 seconds
```

It really shocked me. My server, is running on localhost:8000, and it is empty.

Why? How can I fix it? It is bug in application, or I changed something in my linux machine? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you running on apache?

Comment: @Exprator no. It is local django app

Comment: python manage.py runserver 9999 and go to 127.0.0.1:9999 and check

Comment: @Exprator I tried. Still the same. `This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.`

Comment: are you keeping the runserver command running? or breaking it? and can you check whether you wsgi file is there?

Comment: @Exprator Sure I restarted the server. We don't changed our wsgi, it set to default

Comment: Maybe a deadlock in the code. Use `python -v manage.py run` and see what was imported last. Maybe that gives more insight, or use an `strace` on the process to see what it is doing.

Comment: @KlausD. Last imports: `import 'django.contrib.sites.admin' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f5e0b9d8da0>
Unknown command: 'run'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
import 'gc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>` If I use strace correctly, output is: `root@artem-debian:/home/artem# sudo strace -p 8000 -s 100000
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process`

Comment: My mistake, it is `python -v manage.py runserver`. Also, you gave the wronf PID to the `-p` argument of `strace`.

Comment: @KlausD. I take a look for PyCharm concurrency diagram, I saw no deadlocks

Comment: @KlausD. Last imports with key -v `import 'django.core.management.commands.runserver' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f0f28d532e8> import 'django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f0f28d3c1d0>`Oh, pid. Yeah, it gets me a lot of errors. Finally, I can see log with errors. So it is time to debug.

Comment: @KlausD. I fixed all errors it trace, but connection still refused

Comment: I have similar problem, when code have some obvious problems and django just refuse connection, I have no logs on dev/prod enviroment (debug=false and true).